# unable to access location - failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument

Tags: 14.04, mount, samba, vmware, exfat

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS within a VMware workstation virtual machine and I have managed to setup a network by changing the samba.conf file to the WORKGROUP of my choice. Doing so gave me access to the User folder on the host machine (Win8.1) after providing the proper Username and Password (although I setup a WORKGROUP, here that WORKGROUP was renamed as a Domain for some reason). The problem is that there are several other folder setup on the host machine to be shared (according to windows 8.1) and these folders are displayed in the guest OS (Ubuntu) as expected, however the username and password will be accepted and I cannot gain access to them. In addition, there are other folders in the directory that I have no clue about. They seem to be folders from the host that show up, but I never set up sharing for them to begin with from within Win8.1. Also they have weird syntax that I assume comes from Linux (I am new to Linux) that places a "$" at the end of the folder name, like this:

```
smb://hostpc/folderA$
smb://hostpc/folderB$
```

I messed around with the `smb.conf` file and some features from the Software Center like tools for mounting and manipulating filesystems, but that just ended up mounting another drive in the virtual guest machine.

The bottom line is that a key folder I am trying to access is seen in the network directory, such as `smb://hostpc/folderKEY` , but the gives the following error on opening.

```
unable to access location - failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument
```

The folder belongs to an exFAT partition on an external USB drive attached to the host Machine OS (Win8.1). I can access it no problem from Win8.1, but not Ubuntu in the VM. The other folders belong to the host machine. I would get rid of all passwords to gain access to them, but I do not know how to do that.

Any pointers?